# Error: Could not instantiate bean class - No default constructor found;

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to persist an object of Test type in my database through Spring and Java Persistence API

I have a Test table in my database and I have created the corresponding Entity Class:

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "test")
   @XmlRootElement
   @NamedQueries({
   @NamedQuery(name = "Test2.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM Test t"),
   @NamedQuery(name = "Test2.findByTestId", query = "SELECT t FROM Test t WHERE t.testId = :testId"),
   @NamedQuery(name = "Test2.findByTestint", query = "SELECT t FROM Test t WHERE t.testint = :testint"),
   @NamedQuery(name = "Test2.findByText", query = "SELECT t FROM Test t WHERE t.text = :text")})

public class Test implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "testId")
private Integer testId;
@Column(name = "testint")
private Integer testint;
@Basic(optional = false)

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date endtime;
@Column(name = "text")
private String text;

public Test() {
}

public Test(Integer testId) {
    this.testId = testId;
}

public Test(Integer testId, Date starttime, Date endtime) {
    this.testId = testId;
    this.starttime = starttime;
    this.endtime = endtime;
}

public Integer getTestId() {
    return testId;
}

public void setTestId(Integer testId) {
    this.testId = testId;
}

public Integer getTestint() {
    return testint;
}

public void setTestint(Integer testint) {
    this.testint = testint;
}



public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
}
```

Then I have created a Jpa Class that implements the TestDao interface:

```
 @Repository("testDao")
public class JpaTestDao  implements TestDao {


public JpaTestDao(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    this.emf = emf;
}
@PersistenceUnit
private EntityManagerFactory emf;// = null;
EntityManager em;

public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return emf.createEntityManager();
}
@Transactional
@Override
public void create(Test test) {
    em = null;
    try {
        em = getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(test);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

TestDao interface:

```
public interface TestDao {

    public void create(Test t);
}
```

Finally I am receiving the following error:

```
 Could not instantiate bean class [com.mycompany.jpa.JpaTestDao]: No default constructor   found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mycompany.jpa.JpaTestDao.
```

Could you, please, help me? I cannot figure out what is wrong?

Comment: It's telling you that `JpaTestDao` doesn't have a default constructor, which it doesn't. Add one.

Comment: have you tried to add a default constructor ?

Comment: For starters, `em` is not request-scoped, and you could run into serious problems with your strategy. Make it a local variable instead. Better yet, use `@PersistenceContext`, or better still, just use a `Repository` instead of hand-writing all the boilerplate DA code.

Comment: add public JpaTestDao(){}  in your JpaTestDao class

Comment: Thank you all! I added that default constructor. The weird thing is that I have other JPA classes in my project without that default constructor but never received an error like this.

Comment: Probably because the other JPA classes in your project did not have any constructors that took a parameter.  If you have no constructors in your class at all, you don't need to add a default constructor.  This is typical Java behavior - I would seriously spend some time with Head First Java or a similar book before continuing on with Spring.

Comment: You are so right about your recommendations. I do not have a solid background in Java indeed, but I have been handed over this project that is built in Spring MVC so I have to do it the 'hard way', I have no other choice at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you've added an additional constructor in JpaTestDao, which looks like this:

```
public JpaTestDao(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    this.emf = emf;
}
```

Java will no longer generate a default constructor for you.  You need to add a default constructor:

```
JpaTestDao() {}
```

This is pretty standard Java behavior.  Definitely recommend getting more solid on Java basics before moving to Spring.  Or, maybe you just made an honest mistake.  :)

Additionally, as others have mentioned, you will want to inject EntityManager instead of injecting EntityManagerFactory.  You'll then need to annotate EntityManager with:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="greatUnitName")
```

You will set the unitName in your Spring Config.  A JavaConfig sample is as follows:

```
@Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws SQLException
    {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(envConfig.jpaVendorAdapter());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("java.pkg.pkg1","java.pkg.pkg2");
            factory.setPersistenceUnitName("greatUnitName");

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManager entityManager() throws SQLException
    {
        return entityManagerFactory().getObject().createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws SQLException
    {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }

    //... snip DataSource setup
```